# Eclipse package explorer error in a web application project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I am following a tutorial by Google on "google app engine using java" and trying to make a simple web application. But I am having problem to make a JSP file in the war directory. This is the tutorial page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps

I am using eclipse. When I create a new JSP file in the war directory, it causes an error in the package explorar. The error is:"Your project must be configured to use a JDK in order to use JSPs" 
How can I get rid from this error?

Comment: Which error? Which JSP? Open the *Problems* view and read the error message.

Comment: I have edited the question with the error massage......Thank you JB Nizet

Answer (score 0):

In *Window - Preferences - Java - Installed JREs*, make sure you have a JDK installed, and select it as the default.

Comment: Or at least make sure you have ton installed, and choose that one from your project's Properties dialog's Java Build Path page.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, go into Window>Preferences>Installed JREs and sellect a JDK's JRE.

Them add this line to eclipse.ini:

```
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

That line **must** be in the beginning of the file, before any -vmargs argument, or else Eclipse will crash on start.

Last go into your System's environment variables and add "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin" to the PATH variable, before the "%SystemRoot%\system32" entry.

Those three entries must all point to the same JDK and, of course, must be changed to whatever your JDK's path actually is.

Restart your Eclipse and you should be good to go.